# pegando um JSON e transformando em um Objeto dentro do HTML

Tags: html, json

estou tendo um problema no código abaixo, eu recebo de uma variavel( {{devices}} ) um JSON e tento converter ele num objeto para pegar as informações de quantos dispositivos eu tenho dentro dele e quantos alarmes críticos eu possuo para uma regra de negocio. Porém, o metodo Json.Parse não funciona ou eu não estou conseguindo implementar ele corretamente, segue o código abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="in" hidden> {{devices}} </p>
<p id="out"></p>    
<p id="out1"></p>
<p id="out2"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    var strJson = document.getElementById("in").innerHTML;
    //var objJson = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("in").innerHTML); //motivo do erro, ele para o funcionamento aqui
    var contDev = 0;
    var contCritical = 0;
    var nObj = 0;
    var tipo = "";

    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = typeof strJson; //aqui ele me devolve uma string

    function recursive(obj, key1, key2) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'object'){
        tipo = typeof obj;          
        return;
      }       
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => { //para cada objeto ele procura uma chave 
        if (k == key1 && k[key1] == "c8y_MQTTDevice") {
            contDev = contDev + 1;
        } 
        else if (k == key2 && k[key].Critical == 1) {
            contCritical = contCritical + 1;
        }
        else {
          if (typeof obj[k] == 'object') { //se for outro objeto, dentro de um, chama recursivamente
            recursive(obj[k], key, newValue);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    recursive(objJson, "type", "c8y_ActiveAlarmsStatus")

    document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = "Qtde de Devices: " + contDev;
    document.getElementById("out2").innerHTML = tipo + "___";           
</script>


</body>
```

Json que eu recebo desta variavel!

```
{
  "7097240": {
  "additionParents": {
    "references": [],
    "self": {}
  },
  "owner": "service_device-simulator",
  "childDevices": {
    "references": [],
    "self": 
  },
  "com_cumulocity_model_Agent": {},
  "childAssets": {
    "references": [],
    "self": {}
  },
  "creationTime": "2019-10-01T16:44:15.111+02:00",
  "ts_home": {
    "lng": -47.873174,
    "lat": -22.064469
  },
  "c8y_SupportedOperations": [
    "c8y_Configuration",
    "c8y_Position",
    "c8y_Address",
    "c8y_Mobile",
    "c8y_LocationUpdate",
    "c8y_Firmware",
    "c8y_Restart",
    "c8y_Software"
  ],
  "c8y_Position": {
    "lng": -47.87335,
    "alt": 0,
    "accuracy": 10,
    "lat": -22.065523
  },
  "type": "c8y_MQTTDevice",
  "lastUpdated": "2019-10-18T15:39:31.664+02:00",
  "c8y_ActiveAlarmsStatus": {
    "critical": 0
  },
  "c8y_IsDevice": {},
  "childAdditions": {
    "references": [],
    "self": {}
  },
  "name": "GPS_VW-SC_2 #1",
  "assetParents": {
    "references": [],
    "self": {}
  },
  "deviceParents": {
    "references": [],
    "self":{}
  },
  "self":{},
  "id": "7097240"
}
```

Comment: Mas pq está fazendo parse para Json se isto já é um? Não ficou clara sua questão.

Comment: Entao, eu gostaria de transformar a string q eu estou recebendo em um objeto, para que eu possa trabalhar em cima disso, na verdade queria saber quantos eu estou recebendo e de que tipo.

Comment: Acho que o seu problema é que o Json está inválido.

Comment: Entao eu verifiquei e o erro que da é o seguinte: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:5:21....

Porém, quando joga num site que verifica e organiza esse json para mim, que está vindo como uma string, ele organiza certinho e reclama se tem algum { a mais ou menos!

Comment: Sim se reparar no 2º **self** de cima para baixo, está faltando os **{}**

Comment: Opá LeAndrade, na verdade esse Json creio que está correto, pq nessa parte eu tirei umas informações mesmo, porém eu descobri que o erro q estou tendo é que dentro da primeira tag existe uma variavel {{devices}} e quando tento manipular ele pega essa string e nãoo json que é jogado posteriormente, queria saber se tem como pegar de alguma maneira o conteudo dessa variavel para trabalhar dentro do meu script?

Comment: Mas qual sintaxe é essa `<p id="in" hidden> {{devices}} </p>`?? Usa Angular?

Comment: Na verdade existe uma plataforma em cloud da empresa que trabalho, e eles disponilizam essa variável, e dentro dela uma parte onde posso programar em HTML, e quando eu executo meu programa ele pega o nome da variável para trabalhar e não seu conteúdo, sendo assim, não sei se quando meu script roda ele não pega a informação correta porque a variável é grande de demora á chegar ou de certa maneira o valor dessa variável só é exibida após ser compilado meu programa!

Answer (score 0):

Oi, Lukas.

Tenta substituir:

```
//var objJson = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("in").innerHTML); //motivo do erro, ele para o funcionamento aqui
```

por:

var objJson = JSON.parse(strJson);

Forte abraço!

Comment: Já realizei esse procedimento e ele simplesmente nao roda, gostaria de saber se tem algum outro meio de transformar essa string em um objeto do javascript\

Comment: Então acredito que o problema esteja no formato do json que vc ta recebendo. Pode ser alguma chave que não esteja fechando, conte todos os '{' se não der um número par é porque em algum lugar não esta fechando as chaves.

Comment: Ok vou verificar, muito obrigado pela ajuda!
Mas a logica estaria certa, sou novo com a linguagem de javascript!